# MonoTouch.Dialog Overriding GetCell?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, overriding, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

In MT.Dialog the **Source** class has this:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
......
}
```

In my class:

```
public class BaseDialogViewController : DialogViewController
```

how do I override `public override UITableViewCell GetCell`

This doesn't work:

```
public override GetCell ....
```

Thanks

Note: I am trying to implement: http://fastchicken.co.nz/2012/05/20/earnest-debrief-visual-styles-in-ios-apps-uiappearence-custom-sections-in-monotouch-dialog/

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you getting any exception?

Comment: I can't override it, it's not compiling.

Comment: Ok, what is the compiler error?

Comment: There is nothing to override because I can't get to the item to override as a sub class of MT.Dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DialogViewController` does not have `GetCell` method. So

```
public class BaseDialogViewController : DialogViewController
```

won't work. However `DialogViewController.Source`, a nested type, has a `GetCell` method so

```
public class BaseDialogViewControllerSource : DialogViewController.Source {
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell...
}
```

should work. Of course you need your own subclass of `DialogViewController` to use your new subclass of `Source`.   Which can be done by overriding the `CreateSizingSource` method.